# Problemas al concatenar campos en Select trabajando en MySQL y Vb.NET 2019

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, .net

Estoy tratando de concatenar un resultado de 2 campos en en un Select pero me devuelve siempre el valor 0 (cero).
He verificado la Tabla y no tiene datos nulos en ninguno de los 2 campos.

Será por que uso aliar para las Tablas? Que me sugieren ?

```
Dim Sql = "Select Liq.id As ID, Liq.id_empresa As idEmpresa, & "Liq.f_monto As Monto, " &
"Concat(User.nombre + '-' + User.coduser) as Usuario, " &
"Emp.f_nombre As Empresa " &
"FROM t_liquidacion As Liq " & "Left Join t_empresa As Emp On Liq.id_empresa = Emp.id " & "Left Join t_usuarios As User On Liq.id_user = User.codigo " & "Where (Liq.procesada =" & Tipo & ") ".......
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no mal recuerdo, el CONCAT() en MySQL es con `,` y no con `+` prueba con `Concat(User.nombre , '-' , User.coduser)`

Saludos.

Comment: Ah gracias, lo probaré y comento !!